# Visual Studio Experimental Instance issue after profiling an extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have profiled a Visual Studio 2015 Extension using the Visual Studio Profiler tool, After the profile operation VS experimental instance doesn't load referenced libraries such as NewtonJSON, I'm unable to debug the extension due to this reason. I have reset the experimental instance, cleared the component model cache as well. Please let me know hoe to resolve this.

Comment: Do you mean you vsix project use the some referenced libraries such as NewtonJson, but you could not debug the code which use the libraries. and I create a simple command menu, which use NewtonJson, it works well, please provide a bit more information, such as related code and detailed error message. screen shot.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT: It seems the performance profiler copied release mode binaries to “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\” folder. These binaries are not cleared after the prof profiling is completed, When I try to debug the extension in debug mode after the perf profiling operation, the debugger referenced the release artifacts from above location instead of the debug build. I have deleted the extension related binaries from the above mentioned location and issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by deleting extension related dlls from “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\” folder.